# Projection Transformations

Tags: qgis, postgis, coordinate-system, measurements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I measure area from geographic coordinates?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/711/how-can-i-measure-area-from-geographic-coordinates)

I created my spatial tables in WGS-84 with SRID:4326, I want to transform them to UTM Projection to measure length and areas.Plz Explain..
Is it possible to measure area lengths of spatial features in WGS-1984?
another my doubt is in postgis  can we  store coordinates only in decimal degreed system ? is there way to store in utm projection?

Comment: see also: [Batch convert lat longs to UTM?](http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/8178/batch-convert-lat-longs-to-utm)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[QGIS](http://qgis.org/) will solve most of your problems.  Please download the tutorial PDF of QGIS.

You can also get any measure area lengths in Autocad.
Just insert you data in **Connect** in the home page of Autocad.
Run Area or Lengths calculation Query.